Is there a way to add visibility to context canceled errors so that I know the source of where the cancel is from?
I understand that context canceled is a normal occurrence but what I don't like is that it's cumbersome to investigate why the context was canceled, e.g. it could be a server gracefully shutting down, server cancels a request processing because client doesn't need it anymore, etc.
Instead of just the error context canceled is there a way to augment at the source of the cancellation such that all affected code downstream has access to the reason the context was canceled, e.g. context canceled: grpc request canceled, context canceled: graceful shutdown.

I suspect that the Cause functions, e.g. WithCancelCause, along with context.Cause might be what you are looking for? From the docs: "The WithCancelCause function returns a CancelCauseFunc, which takes an error and records it as the cancellation cause. Calling Cause on the canceled context or any of its children retrieves the cause. If no cause is specified, Cause(ctx) returns the same value as ctx.Err(). "

Yes, you could use context.WithCancelCause and context.Cause, like Brits correctly remarks (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var errReason = errors.New("cancellation reason")

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancelCause(context.Background())

    cancel(errReason)

    err := doNothing(ctx)

    fmt.Println(err)
}

func doNothing(ctx context.Context) error {
    <-ctx.Done()

    return fmt.Errorf("doNothing canceled: %w", context.Cause(ctx))
}

